# Need to join certain lines based on multiple-line pattern match

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that looks like this:

```
2014-05-01 00:30:45,511
ZZZ|1|CE|web1||etc|etc
ZZZ|1|CE|web2||etc|etc
ZZZ|1|CE|web3|asd|SDAF
2014-05-01 00:30:45,511
ZZZ|1|CE|web1||etc|etc
ZZZ|1|CE|web2||etc|etc
ZZZ|1|CE|web3|asd|SDAF
```

I want to convert this into 2 lines by replacing the newlines followed by certain patterns with pipes. I want:

```
2014-05-01 00:30:45,511|ZZZ|1|CE|web1||etc|etc|ZZZ|1|CE|web2||etc|etc|ZZZ|1|CE|web3|asd|SDAF
2014-05-01 00:30:45,511|ZZZ|1|CE|web1||etc|etc|ZZZ|1|CE|web2||etc|etc|ZZZ|1|CE|web3|asd|SDAF
```

I am trying multiline match with perl:

```
cat file | perl -pe 's/\nZZZ/\|ZZZ/m'
```

but this does not match.

I can do perl -pe 's/\n//m' but that is too much; I need to match '\nZZZ' so that only lines beginning with ZZZ are joined to the previous line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to indicate slurp mode using the [`-0777`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) switch because you're using a regular expression that's trying to match across multiple lines.

The full solution:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(?=ZZZ)/|/g' file
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-0777`: slurp files whole
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `s/\n(?=ZZZ)/|/g`: Replace any newline that is followed by ZZZ with a |

Comment: Cool solution but what does the `(?=...)` do? It works without it, too.

Comment: @malana `(?=...)` is a positive look ahead assertion.  In this case it matches the ZZZ, but does not include it in what is replaced in the right hand side.  Alternatively, one could use a matching group `s/\n(ZZZ)/|$1/g`, but I prefer the other style.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you want to avoid slurp mode:

```
perl -pe 'chomp unless eof; /\|/ and s/^/|/ or $.>1 and s/^/\n/' filename.txt
```

- Add a record separator to the beginning of the line if it contains record separators.
- Otherwise start a new line if we are past the first line.
- Keep the new line at the end of the file.

Comment: +1: Nicely done. I made some minor corrections to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Lookahead, which does not kill your `ZZZ` Part

```
cat file | perl -pe 's/(\n(?=ZZZ))/|/gm'
```

EDIT: [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fF2dB2)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard pattern. It looks like this. The path to the input file is expected as a parameter on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line;
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  if ( /^ZZZ/ ) {
    $line .= '|' . $_;
  }
  else {
    print $line, "\n" if $line;
    $line = $_;
  }
}
print $line, "\n" if $line;
```

**output**

```
2014-05-01 00:30:45,511|ZZZ|1|CE|web1||etc|etc|ZZZ|1|CE|web2||etc|etc|ZZZ|1|CE|web3|asd|SDAF
2014-05-01 00:30:45,511|ZZZ|1|CE|web1||etc|etc|ZZZ|1|CE|web2||etc|etc|ZZZ|1|CE|web3|asd|SDAF
```